# Set placeholder to textbox type password using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the HTML with PHP code:

```
<input name="password" class="text passplace" type="password" value="<?=$password;?>" maxlength="255" />
```

I want to set the placeholder to this field but it not work, it still show data on textbox that data from database (see code above).I have tried to user the Jquery code as below:

**Jquery code**

```
 <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
             // $(".passplace").val();
           $(".passplace").attr("placeholder","Mot de passe");

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it still show data on textbox that data from database

Assuming you're referring to the `value` attribute, that is how placeholders work. When there is a value the placeholder will not be visible. If you remove the value the placeholder should appear.

The line of code you've commented out is halfway to solving the issue. You would need to pass it the empty string to clear the input. Currently it will return the *current* value, rather than setting it:

```
$(".passplace").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to empty the value first :

```
$(".passplace").val('');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I already tried with this,but it still not work!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.passplace').val('').prop("placeholder","Mot de passe");
```

You can also use:

```
$('input[name="password"]').val('').prop("placeholder","Mot de passe");
```